# Can multiple versions of a snap be installed on a system?

Tags: chromium, snapcraft

I am running Linux Mint 18.3 XFCE and have installed snapd on it. I have the stable version of Chromium installed via snap and would also like to try out the beta version. However, when I attempt to install the beta version snap, I get a message back that I already have Chromium installed. Is it possible to have the stable and beta versions installed at the same time, or do I have to remove one to use the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove one to use the other by running `sudo snap refresh --channel=beta chromium` (`refresh` is the snap term for "upgrade").  Snaps can only co-exist when the *snap_name* is different.

**UPDATE:** [Parallel Installs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/parallel-installs) are now a thing, however, it is still in experimental status(as of 2021/6/14) and may not work well for many snaps.